# Display variable on dialog --msgbox

Tags: shell-script, arithmetic

I want to output a arithmetic progression on a dialog message box, but the --msgbox attribute is showing them as plain text

### My code:

```
while :
do
    sequence=(1 10 100 1000 10000)
    dialog --stdout --msgbox '${sequence[*]}' 0 0
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quote is preventing the shell from recognizing the variable interpolation. That's what the single quote is supposed to do. Replace your single quotes with double quotes and you will get the output I believe you're looking for. You should also realize that this code is an infinite loop that will keep displaying the dialog box the same way no matter how many times you hit enter to close the dialog box.